# Maven com.google cannot be resolved to type

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

New to Maven. I built my project using Maven and generate a Protobuf executable and generate the source to my project. I'm using eclipse and compiling in Java. I don't seem to have the library properly imported so I get a lot of errors when viewing the generated code through eclipse.

I am receiving error `Maven com.google cannot be resolved to type`

I've looked at numerous suggestions and can't seem to find a resolution to this problem. My build path seems to be correct from what I think.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.henosisknot.com</groupId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<name>ChatBot-Henosisknot</name>
<url>henosisknot.com</url>
<description>Chatbot for henosisknot.com</description>
<artifactId>Chatbot-Henosisknot</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <modules>
                <module>com</module>
        </modules>
      </profile>
</profiles>
<organization>
    <name>Henosisknot.com</name> 
 </organization>

<properties>

<!-- protobuf paths -->
<protobuf.input.directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/proto</protobuf.input.directory>
<protobuf.output.directory>${project.basedir}/src/</protobuf.output.directory>
<project.build.dir>${project.basedir}/build</project.build.dir>

<!-- library versions -->
<build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.9.1</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
<maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.8</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
<maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.10</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
<maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.2</maven-shade-plugin.version>
<os-maven-plugin.version>1.4.1.Final</os-maven-plugin.version>
<protobuf.version>3.0.0</protobuf.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


 <build>
    <extensions>
    <!-- provides os.detected.classifier (i.e. linux-x86_64, osx-x86_64) property -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${os-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

    <directory>${project.build.dir}/classes</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/users/andor/workspace/Chatbot-Henosisknot/build/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <!-- copy protoc binary into build directory -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-protoc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                                <artifactId>protoc</artifactId>
                                <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
                                <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
                                <type>exe</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- compile proto buffer files using copied protoc binary -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-protoc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="protoc.filename" value="protoc-${protobuf.version}-${os.detected.classifier}.exe"/>
                            <property name="protoc.filepath" value="${project.build.dir}/${protoc.filename}"/>
                            <chmod file="${protoc.filepath}" perm="ugo+rx"/>
                            <mkdir dir="${protobuf.output.directory}" />
                            <path id="protobuf.input.filepaths.path">
                                <fileset dir="${protobuf.input.directory}">
                                    <include name="**/*.proto"/>
                                </fileset>
                            </path>
                            <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="protobuf.input.filepaths" refid="protobuf.input.filepaths.path"/>
                            <exec executable="${protoc.filepath}" failonerror="true">
                                <arg value="-I"/>
                                <arg value="${protobuf.input.directory}"/>
                                <arg value="--java_out"/>
                                <arg value="${protobuf.output.directory}"/>
                                <arg line="${protobuf.input.filepaths}"/>
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <protocExecutable>/usr/local/bin/protoc</protocExecutable>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/com/**</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>main.java.com.chatbot.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.chatbot.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing to remember with Apache Maven is that a key tenet in it's design is the principle of "convention over configuration". This means that if we stick to the maven conventions then our pom.xml files become a lot smaller and simpler.

And you seem to have configured your way into trouble. The key elements for your build are:

- You're building a jar file
- It contains classes that you have written
- It contains classes that will be generated from .proto files that are in your source tree.

### Build the right kind of artifact

As you're building a jar file, your pom should declare the packaging correctly:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

### Process the .proto message files

Now, I'm going to focus on processing your .proto files because that seems to be causing you the most trouble right now.

#### Install protoc if necessary

The first thing it needs is an executable copy of the `protoc` executable.
Your sample pom.xml above is both downloading a version from the maven repository into `${project.build.dir}`, aka the `target` directory, **and** trying to use `/usr/local/bin/protoc` for the same purpose. 
You may or may not actually have the latter in place. If not then:

If your `target` directory contains `protoc-3.5.1-1-osx-x86_64.exe` then we can use that, otherwise:

1. Point your browser at [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org);
2. Search for `com.google.protobuf`;
3. Click on the `protoc` link and directly download the version that you want.

Then:

1. Copy the downloaded artifact to `/usr/local/bin/`
2. Rename it to `protoc`, and
3. Make it executable:

   `chmod a+x protoc`

#### Set up the protobuf-maven-plugin

You have already discovered the [protobuf-maven-plugin](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/index.html). 
Setting this up is the key to resolving your remaining problems.

By convention, it expects to find your .proto files in:

```
src/
  main/
    proto/
```

with a conventional java package structure below that. Therefore:

*Move the .proto files into this location.*

Your `protobuf-maven-plugin` configuration is then ok, although I suspect that you do not need the:

```
 <goal>test-compile</goal>
```

line.

### Last steps

Finally, you should completely remove the `maven-compiler-plugin` declaration.
Remember that maven conventions will be used to set this up properly.

As `protoc` is now hand installed, we can get rid of some large slabs of XML from your pom file:

```
<description>ffffff</description>
<artifactId>fffffff</artifactId>

<!-- you're building a jar -->
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<!-- the profiles section was meaningless -->

<organization>
    <name>fffff</name>
</organization>

<properties>

    <!-- protobuf paths -->
    <!-- you were fighting maven with these properties -->

    <!-- library versions -->
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.2</maven-shade-plugin.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <!-- generate java from .proto files -->
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocExecutable>/usr/local/bin/protoc</protocExecutable>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- maven compiler plugin declaration is usually redundant unless you want a specific version -->

        <!-- I have not addressed this... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: After a lot of twiddling around I found out there was two issue: As you correctly pointed out, my convention was incorrect. Specifically I was locating my proto files in a different directory (/main/com/proto). While this was wrong, this wasn't the bit that was causing me massive problems. The bit that was causing me a lot of headache was that the .m2/repository directories needed to be cleared, and this was causing conflict with the java code. luckily I came across a post that led me into the write direction. I needed all my dependencies to redownload.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because ultimately it does address and clearly explain some of the key problems I was having in my original pom.xml file.